# React-native autocomplete issue ("Objects are not valid as a Reach child")

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, autocomplete

I'm trying to use Autocomplete in React-native but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Here a minimal example of code showing what I'm doing:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';

const DATA =
[{"id": 1,"title": "test1"},{"id": 2,"title": "test2"},{"id": 3,"title": "test3"}]

const App = () => {

 const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          data={DATA}
          value={query}
          onChangeText={setQuery}

          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TouchableOpacity 
              onPress={() => {}}>
              <Text> 
                  {item.title}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>  
  );
};
```

I reduced the code to the very minimum.

However, I keep getting error:
"Objecs are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id,title}"

It seems I'm missing something very obvious about renderItem (I guess), but since I'm stuck since a few hours, another eye could spot what I'm doing wrong.. any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer.

It seems, I haven't read correctly the list of props for Autocomplete: in fact, renderItem must be passed inside an option called "flatListProps".

Correct code is below:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';

const DATA =
[{"id": 1,"title": "test1"},{"id": 2,"title": "test2"},{"id": 3,"title": "test3"}]

const App = () => {

 const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          data={DATA}
          value={query}
          onChangeText={setQuery}

          flatListProps={{
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps: 'always',
            keyExtractor: (item) => item.id,
              renderItem: ( ({item}) => (
                <TouchableOpacity 
                  onPress={() => {}}>
                  <Text> 
                      {item.title}
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ))
          }}

        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>  
  );
};
```

Comment: this solution is fix if not able to select any item. Awesome

Comment: @Damian Im trying to use the autocomplete for getting data remotly from a Google API, all works good when I type because I can see in my console the results but by some reason i cant see the autocomplete dropdown. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Your destructuring was wrong. do like below `{id,title}`. `renderItem` is array of iteration so its look like object.

```
renderItem={({title,id}) => (
            <TouchableOpacity 
              onPress={() => {}}>
              <Text> 
                  {title}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not working. I keep getting the same error (objects are not valid as a React child)

Answer (score 0):

```
renderItem={({ item, i }) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity key={i} onPress={() => ()}>
                    <Text>{item.label}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
```

You have to pass the index to key.

Comment: Thanks, but this is also not working. I still get the same error..

Comment: my be this will help https://www.akashmittal.com/react-error-objects-not-valid-react-child/#:~:text=Check%20this%20demo%20%E2%80%93-,Solution,(What%20is%20JSX%3F).&text=Although%2C%20objects%20can%20not%20be,will%20work%20without%20any%20issue.